# Does a SQL query with fewer attributes cost less?

Tags: sql, utilization

My question is very simple - Does a SQL query with fewer attributes cost less?

Example:
Let's say our `users` table have 10 columns like `userId`, `name`, `phone`, `email`, ...

```
SELECT name, phone FROM users WHERE userId='id'
```

is cheapier than this

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId='id'
```

Is it true in the perspective of resource utilization?

Comment: In any case, never use evil `SELECT *`. Always name, and properly qualify (and, if necessary, alias) only the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: What at some point in time a column named `json_props` is added that contains multiple megabytes of data. If you use `select *` then suddenly you are sending a lot of data over the network that you don't actually need

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: The two queries are different.  You should use the one that does what you really need.  In terms of performance, an index on `id` is much, much more important than what columns you select, unless some of the columns are inordinately wide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends.

It is certainly possible that limiting the number of columns in the projection improves performance but it depends on what indexes are available.  If we assume that `userId` is either the primary key or at least an indexed column, you'd expect database's optimizer to determine which row(s) to fetch by doing a lookup using an index that has `userId` as the leading column.

If there is an index on `(user_id, phone)` or if `phone` is an included column on the index if your database supports that concept, the database can get the `phone` from the index it used to find the row(s) to return.  In this way, the database never has to visit the actual table to fetch the `phone`.  An index that has all the information the database needs to process the query without visiting the table is known as a "covering index".  Roughly speaking, it is probably roughly as costly to search the index for the rows to return as it is to visit the table to fetch additional columns for the projection.  If you can limit the number of columns in the projection in order to use a covering index, that to may significantly reduce the cost of the query.  Even more significantly if visiting the table to fetch every column involves doing multiple reads because of chained rows or out-of-line LOB columns in Oracle, TOAST-able data types in PostgreSQL, etc.

Reducing the number of columns in the projection will also decrease the amount of data that needs to be sent over the network and the amount of memory required on the client to process that data.  This tends to be most significant when you have larger fields.  For example, if one of the columns in the `users` table happened to be an LDAP path for the user's record, that could easily be hundreds of characters in length and account for half the network bandwidth consumed and half the memory used on the middle tier.  Those things probably aren't critical if you're building a relatively low traffic internal line of business application that needs to serve a few hundred users.  It is probably very critical if you're building a high volume SaaS application that needs to serve millions of users.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - Included that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in the grand scheme of things, both are negligible.
If the data is stored by rows, there isn't much of a difference as retrieving a line of data doesn't cost much. perhaps if one of the columns was particularly large then avoiding its retrieval would be beneficial.

but if the data is stored by columns, then the first one is cheaper as each entry is stored in a different location.

Comment: It's not only the cost of retrieval, it's also about the cost of sending that data over the network.

Comment: In Oracle, that's simply wrong, as @Justin explained. If the you need only two columns, and both are included in an index, you save a lot of IO by not having to go to the table.

Comment: I basically agree with this answer.  In the grand scheme of things, an extra data page load after traversing an index is probably not particularly important -- and might even be hard to measure if the data pages are already loaded in memory.  And if there is no index, then a full table scan is needed anyway.  There *is* a difference, but micro-optimizations are probably not important, except in a columnar database or if some columns are particularly wide.  That said, Jusin's answer is also even more correct.